# In Haskell, what is the reason for needing to convert from Data.Text.Internal?

Tags: haskell, text

`Text.Regex.TDFA.Text` is the only one that provides instances for `RegexLike Regex Text` using internal Text types.

Can instances of classes with `Data.Text.Lazy` be derived from instances of `Data.Text.Internal`? How can I improve this code?

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Text.Regex.TDFA
import Text.Regex.Base.Context()
import Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike()
import Text.Regex.TDFA.Text
import Data.Function (on)

(<?>) :: T.Text -> T.Text -> Bool
(<?>) = on (=~) T.toStrict
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be missing something, but it seems you have missed [the module containing lazy `Text` instances for the regex-tdfa classes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2/docs/Text-Regex-TDFA-Text-Lazy.html) . If that's what's happening, then you need only change

```
 import Text.Regex.TDFA.Text
```

to

```
 import Text.Regex.TDFA.Text.Lazy
```

Note that what is called `Text` in the module `Data.Text.Internal` is the same as what is called `Text` in `Data.Text` -- i.e., it's "strict" `Text`.  The lazy text type is defined in a different internal module (basically as a specialized list of strict texts.)  So it's not as though these are two ways of viewing the same thing, if that's what you were thinking.